# Drawing line segment connecting two points on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a point plot with two different points on each category and I want to create a line segment joining the two points on each row.

```
items %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(med_buy_price = mean(buy_value, na.rm = TRUE),
            med_sell_price = mean(sell_value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("med_buy_price", "med_sell_price"),
               names_to = "measure",
               values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = category)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = measure), size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a line segment, you need to have start and endpoints for the segment. Thus, you can stay with the wide format, so no `pivot_longer` needed.

Then create individual `geom_point` for sell and buy value and a `geom_segment` combining both points.

This code will work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

items <- tribble(
  ~category, ~buy_value, ~sell_value,
  "Wallpaper", 2000, 5200,
  "Usables", 500, 12500,
  "Umbrellas", 200, 1800
)

items %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(med_buy_price = mean(buy_value, na.rm = TRUE),
            med_sell_price = mean(sell_value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = med_buy_price, y = category), size = 3, color = "red")+
  geom_point(aes(x = med_sell_price, y = category), size = 3, color = "green")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = med_buy_price, xend = med_sell_price, y = category, yend = category))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist on using `geom_point` you could try `geom_errorbar` which simplifies thing a little bit

```
items %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(med_buy_price = mean(buy_value, na.rm = TRUE),
            med_sell_price = mean(sell_value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin=med_buy_price,xmax=med_sell_price, y = category)) +
  geom_errorbar(width=0.1)
```